# date field should not be editable by all the roles other than SysAdmin role

Tags: validation

I have to make the field non editable for the users except for the user of System Admin.

Comment: Don't give edit access for the users in profile level

Comment: I've downvoted this because (as worded) it's an extremely basic question that should be easy/quick to google, and it doesn't appear that you've done any research at all. Giving a more detailed description of what you're trying to do (I want to restrict editing this field because <insert description here> and need to enforce this in <page layout/visualforce/apex/etc...>). Is there a reason why FLS (field level security) doesn't take care of your need here?

Answer (score 2):

#### You can change the option with help Field Accessibility

- Go to the **Search Box** -> type **Field Accessibility**
- Select the **object** you wanted apply the Accessibility.
- then Click on the **View by Profiles**
- select the **System Administrator** from list box.
- select the field and change editable.
- click Save.

Similarly

- Follow the above step instead of the system admin select other profile and change editable to Read Only.

#### Even in simple way when you create a field with **read only** access and **save**.

- Then Follow the above step only for **system Administrator**.
- So that you can avoid by keep change other profile read only access for that date field

Answer (score 0):

you can use [global variables](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&language=en_US&type=0) accessible from validation rules

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(
         FieldName__c
    ),
    $UserRole.DeveloperName != 'System Admin'
)
```

Comment: While this does work, it has some serious implications in the UI. Using FLS, the field is rendered as read-only, while using a validation rule, the user will not be told the field is read-only until attempting to save. This means that the user might have to cancel their edits and start over if they can't remember what the original date was in the field. I would recommend this only as a last resort.

Comment: @sfdcfox agree with you. I thought, that topic starter knows about FLS, but for some reason it is not suitable to achieve desired result.